# Plotter: What is fixed - the height or the width

Tags: java, printing, plot

I am fixing some printing (plotter) problems in our java code(windows 32).

The paper is 50 meter roll , loaded on to plotter.  The paper It 36 inch "wide".  I am printing image 36inch by 108 inch.  When I print what is with height and width I can use?

[ FYI. The testing is done using print to file, No paper is wasted :)  ]

Thanks,
Jayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [*Printing: A Basic Printing Program*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html): "The [`PageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html) class describes the page orientation (portrait or landscape) and its size and imageable area in units of 1/72nd of an inch."

Addendum: Note that the width and height methods of [`PageFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PageFormat.html) take into account the orientation of the page.